# Golang native http client hangs on particular URI

Tags: go, https

This is a small peace of code:

```
//resp, err := http.Get("https://alfabank.ru")
resp, err := http.Get("https://google.com")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(body))
```

It works fine with Google, but hangs on alfabank (try to uncomment first line and comment second).
I can't figure out on which side this problem :(
But, for example,

```
curl https://alfabank.ru
```

works fine.

So, I think, that the problem in Golang client.

I tried to use tcpdump and see infinite traffic between my machine and remote server.

Could you help me to figure out the problem?

**UPDATE**: following the advice from comments

Ok, curl sends this headers:

```
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: alfabank.ru
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
```

So, I tried

```
req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, "http://alfabank.ru", nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
req.Header.Add("Accept", "*/*")
req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "curl/7.54.0")

client := http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
```

It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Set the appropriate headers.

Comment: That server seems to have a broken http2 implementation.

Comment: You probably should to post the solution as an answer. There is an option to  self answer and it's OK by SO rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**:

Thank you to [JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32880/jimb), problem in http2 protocol.

So, disabling http2 helps me to solve the problem:

```
http.DefaultClient.Transport = &http.Transport{
    TLSNextProto: make(map[string]func(authority string, c *tls.Conn) http.RoundTripper),
}
```

Comment: I am also facing similar issue, could you please look at it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67711312/golang-http-defaultclient-http-request-hanged-from-linux-service