# GoLang(cgp) http.Client get request hangs from Linux daemon process

Tags: c++, linux, go, systemd

I have written a simple GoLang function which makes HTTP GET request using http.Client and prints the response string. I then exported it as C function in .so file using following command.

```
go build -o libapp.so -buildmode=c-shared libapp.go
```

Then using this .SO and .h, called exported Go function from my C test program. Below is the command I used to compile and build my C test program.

```
gcc -o goclient goclient.c ./libapp.so
```

Here is CheckConnection function in GoLang

```
var file io.Writer

//export CheckConnection
func CheckConnection() {

path := "/opt/logs/gologs.txt"
f, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)    
}
file = f
log.SetOutput(file)
log.Print("---------Logging started---------")
log.Print("Hello from CheckConnection\r\n")

log.Print("CheckConnection creating http.Client: step1")

var netTransport = &http.Transport{
  Dial: (&net.Dialer{
Timeout: 10 * time.Second,
  }).Dial,
  TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,    
}
log.Print("CheckConnection creating http.Client: step2")

var myClient = &http.Client{
  Timeout: time.Second * 10,
  Transport: netTransport,
}
log.Print("CheckConnection creating http.Client: step3")

res,err := myClient.Get("https://www.google.com")
log.Print("CheckConnection creating http.Client: step4")
if err!= nil {
log.Print("Error ",err)
}
log.Print("CheckConnection creating http.Client: step5")
data,_ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
log.Print("CheckConnection creating http.Client: step6")
res.Body.Close()
log.Print("CheckConnection creating http.Client: step7")
log.Print("Resp code ",res.StatusCode)
log.Print("Data ",data)

defer log.Print("Returning from CheckConnection");

}
```

Thread gets blocked at below line, does not timeout or gives error -

```
 res,err := myClient.Get("https://www.google.com")
```

This happens when CheckConnection() function gets called from Daemon process. If I call this function from C,C++ main() process then it works. I have reported same issue on GitHub https://github.com/golang/go/issues/47077. It has sample code to reproduce the issue (Sample.zip).

Please refer to GitHub issue https://github.com/golang/go/issues/47077 for sample reproducible code.

Adding go env below

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="386"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/root/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/root/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE="golang.org,googlesource.com"
GOMODCACHE="/home/nilesh/golang/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/nilesh/golang"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_386"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.16.4"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GO386="sse2"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/home/nilesh/SVN/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m32 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build718813889=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Comment: can you descibe better the service setup you did ? like systemd, or old style sysv. does it happen on a specific OS ? Which go version ? go env ? kernel version ? Have you tried to reproduce this into a container ?

Comment: I am using go version 'go1.16.4 linux/386' on CentOS 7. I havent tried on other linux flavor. Service is of type systemd. Not tried on container as , this code should work on CentOS7 only. Strange thing is - test application works on same machine but from service call gets hang.

Comment: is it possible you share the C code, the command to compile and your service definition ? the stuff needed to make the description complete.

Comment: C code is simple, just include header file generated using command 'go build -o mygolib.so -buildmode=c-shared mygolib.go' and call the CheckConnection() from main(). Use command  'gcc -o client client.c ./mygolib.so' to compile C code.  Meanwhile let me see if I can share you service definition.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this issue with sample code. And it seems issue is when calling http.client get call from daemon process. Here is the issue I have created on GitHub for same. It has Sample.zip contains both libapp.go and goclient.c files. CheckConnection() called from main() works fine , but CheckConnection() called from daemon process gets hang. github.com/golang/go/issues/47077

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using cgp shared library in your C/C++ program on linux and if you are calling these functions from forked process then make sure you should consider below points.

1. Do not statically link the shared library, instead load it dynamically using dlopen, dlsym, dlclose.
2. Make sure while doing above you are not providing shared lib name during linking

This solved my problem and I am able to to make network calls from my forked process.

Answer (score 0):

By default there is no timeout for the DefaultClient. Could you try with own client with timeout set up?

```
var myClient = &http.Client{
  Timeout: time.Second * 10,
}
```

Comment: I used timeout setting as suggested by you. But still call is stuck at Do(req) call. It does not timed out.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this issue with some sample. And it seems issue is when calling http.client get call from daemon process.  Here is the issue I have created on GitHub for same. It has Sample.zip contains both libapp.go and goclient.c files.  CheckConnection() called from main() works fine , but CheckConnection() called from daemon process gets hang. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/47077